# How to specify LaTeX output format in Astropy

Tags: python, latex, astropy

I just started to use [`Astropy`](http://www.astropy.org/) to write tables in LaTeX format. It does the job, however, when I write down the table, the units normalized to large masses, typically 1e6 solar masses, are displayed without the scientific notation.

An example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def table_write():
    from astropy.io import ascii
    import astropy.table
    import astropy.units as u


    #fake data, ~ the same order of magnitude of real ones
    Mbh = [1e1,  7e3]
    t_final = [13, 12.2]

    tab = astropy.table.Table([Mbh, t_final],
            names =  ['Mbh', 't_final'])
    tab['Mbh'].unit = '1e6 Msun'
    tab['t_final'].unit = 'Gyr'

    ascii.write(tab,
            Writer=ascii.Latex,
            latexdict=ascii.latex.latexdicts['AA'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    table_write()
```

The output is

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline \hline
Mbh & t_final \\
$\mathrm{1000000\,M_{\odot}}$ & $\mathrm{Gyr}$ \\
\hline
10.0 & 13.0 \\
7000.0 & 12.2 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

which is fine, except for

> \mathrm{1000000\,M_{\odot}}

which should be a nice

> \mathrm{10^{6}\,M_{\odot}}

So, I would like to format a part of the unit.
The [documentation](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/units/format.html#astropy-units-format) seems to report a way to do this, but it is absolutely not clear.

Comment: Neither output is something I’d call “fine” by a long shot. Instead, astrophy should output code that uses the LaTeX ‹siunitx› package, which is customisable in LaTeX itself. Is this possible?

Comment: Is siunitx available, for example, in mathjax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a **new unit** `u.Msun` with the `astropy.units.def_unit()` method. If you want, you can also specify the **column's format** to scientific notation with the argument `formats` of the `astropy.io.ascii.write()` method,

```
from astropy.io import ascii
import astropy.table
import astropy.units as u

def table_write():

    #fake data, ~ the same order of magnitude of real ones
    Mbh = [1e1,  7e3]
    t_final = [13, 12.2]

    tab = astropy.table.Table([Mbh, t_final],
            names =  ['Mbh', 't_final'])

    # Define new unit with LaTeX format
    new_Msun = u.def_unit('1E6 Msun', 10**6*u.Msun, format={'latex': r'10^6\,M_{\odot}'})

    tab['Mbh'].unit = new_Msun
    tab['t_final'].unit = u.Gyr

    ascii.write(tab,
            Writer=ascii.Latex,
            latexdict=ascii.latex.latexdicts['AA'],
            formats={'Mbh':'%.0E'}) # Set the column's format to scientific notation


if __name__ == "__main__":
    table_write()
```

**LaTeX:**

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline \hline
Mbh & t_final \\
$\mathrm{10^6\,M_{\odot}}$ & $\mathrm{Gyr}$ \\
\hline
1E+01 & 13.0 \\
7E+03 & 12.2 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

As you can see here the new unit is actually 10^6 times the Sun mass, whereas the text formatting with LaTeX is right,

[image]